# boosting a particular VALUE rather than FIELD in solr query

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-boost

Consider following two queries:
    query1: term1 term2
    query2: term1 term1 term2
Will there be any difference in searched documents ordering?? I mean will solr give more weightage to "term1" in query2. As per my understanding solr should do that. But I am not sure and need comments from community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but there is no need to use a hack like this.  You can boost a query term, like:

```
term1^2 term2
```

See the [QueryParser syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Boosting%20a%20Term)